# Article transfer in Elsevier

Tags: publications, journals

I submitted an article to a journal of Elsevier. This paper was peer-reviewed and I received a transfer suggestion to a list of five suggested journals of Elsevier. I revised my article according to the reviewers' comments and submitted it to one of these journals. The new journal has a higher impact factor and my submission is subscription. The status of submission is "Submitted to Journal" for a week. My questions:

1. In this case, the status of submission is needed to change to "With Editor", "Under Review" and "Decision in Process"? or may be my revised article has been sent to the original reviewers of the first journal?
2. How is the chance of getting published in this case?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand, you submitted a paper, it was sent out for review and then rejected with the option to transfer *after* review but *before* you submitted revisions. So you revised it and resubmitted through the transfer desk.

Your article should have been sent to the new journal where it will be assigned a new editor and the process will start all over. So, yes, you'll probably see the status change to "With Editor" or "Editor Assigned" first. Then they may or may not ask for new reviews. If the original reviewers never actually saw your revisions, I bet they will just reach back out to them, but it depends on many things.

It's been a while because the transfer desk is slow and the new journal may be slow to process it. In my experience the transfer desk is slower than just resubmitting from scratch (and not always more convenient).

It's impossible to know the chances of getting published. It depends on the paper, the reviews, the journal, and why it was rejected in the first place. I would say the chances are probably no better or worse than if you had submitted the paper normally. Big publishers have an interest in putting out as many papers as possible and keeping papers in their portfolio so, unless a paper is really awful, they usually offer to transfer.

Comment: Thanks! My submitted work is a research-survey (feature) paper and the first journal publishes only original papers. I revised and submitted my work as a feature paper in the second journal. The original reviewers have not seen the revised version, then I think my paper will be submitted to them.  Do you have any positive experience in transferring?